# "not a valid package archive" when trying to install PHP extension?

Tags: linux, centos, php

I'm running CENTOS 6.6 on a VPS and am trying to install [the ZMQ PHP extension](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php) and tried installing using the command shown in the instructions:

```
sudo pecl install zmq-beta
```

However, it fails, showing this as the output:

```
root@host [/zmq]#  sudo pecl install zmq-beta
downloading zmq-1.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download zmq-1.1.2.tgz (39,573 bytes)
..........done: 39,573 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/root/tmp/pear/cache/zmq-1.1.2.tgz"
Download of "pecl/zmq" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/zmq"
Download failed
install failed
```

I also tried:

```
sudo pecl install -Z zmq-beta
```

And:

```
sudo pecl install --nocompress zmq-beta
```

But I get the same error.

Why is this error occuring?

Comment: Did you run `pecl channel-update` like it said?

Comment: @Mikel Yes, I did run that command, but the same error still occurs, just without that line. I'll update my question to the output after the update.

Answer (score 0):

SOA #1.
It think, that problem is in downloaded archive. Check md5sum of archive:

```
[root@centos6 ~]# md5sum /root/tmp/pear/cache/zmq-1.1.2.tgz 
74da2fc1aa83e6fa27acffb9a37596b9  /root/tmp/pear/cache/zmq-1.1.2.tgz
```

If it isn't the same - remove it and try download it again.

Alternativly - you can invoke pecl with -vv parameter - then you should see more about error, and path from where file was downloaded. Mime was from http://pecl.php.net/get/zmq-1.1.2.tgz

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, to solve it:

- First download zmq-1.1.2.tgz (https://pecl.php.net/get/zmq-1.1.2.tgz)
- Extract **tgz** to get the **tar** archive
- `cd` to the tar file directory, and install this pecl package with `sudo pear install -O zmq-1.1.2.tar`

And it works for me.

Why ? I think it is because pecl command try to find a **package.xml** file in the **tgz**, but the file is still archived in a tar archive inside this tgz file.

So downloading and extract it manually do the job.